# Guard is not detecting controller files changes

Tags: guard

I have a Rails API so all controllers live in `app/controllers/api/v1/` and when I save a controller file the test file does not run.

For example, I have a file `app/controllers/api/v1/images_controller.rb` and a test file in `spec/requests/api/v1/images_controller_spec.rb`.
Whan I save the controller file the test file is not run, however when I ave the test file the test file runs.

This is my Guardfile

```
clearing :on
guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
  require 'guard/rspec/dsl'
  dsl = Guard::RSpec::Dsl.new(self)

  # Feel free to open issues for suggestions and improvements

  # RSpec files
  rspec = dsl.rspec

  watch(rspec.spec_helper) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_support) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_files)

  # Ruby files
  ruby = dsl.ruby
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(ruby.lib_files)

  # Rails files
  rails = dsl.rails(view_extensions: %w[erb haml slim])
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(rails.app_files)
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(rails.views)
  watch(rails.controllers) do |m|
    [
      rspec.spec.call("routing/#{m[1]}_routing"),
      rspec.spec.call("controllers/#{m[1]}_controller"),
      rspec.spec.call("acceptance/#{m[1]}")
    ]
  end
  # Rails config changes
  watch(rails.spec_helper)     { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rails.routes)          { "#{rspec.spec_dir}/routing" }
  watch(rails.app_controller)  { "#{rspec.spec_dir}/controllers" }
end
```

Appreciate your help 'cuase I don't udenrstand how it all works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the question myself. I added the test file to `spec/controllers/api/v1/` and saved the controller file and the test ran so it told me that I need another rule

`rspec.spec.call("requests/#{m[1]}_controller")`

and it works.